# How to minimize the number of edge crossings with diagrammer, R?

Tags: r, graph, diagrammer

When I plot a network graph with diagrammer, like the following toy example...

```
library(DiagrammeR)
Dia <- function(edg, nodesd) { 
         nodes <-   create_node_df(  n=length(nodesd), label=nodesd,  
         width=0.3) 
         edges <- create_edge_df(from = edg$EveFrom, to = edg$EveTo, 
                rel = "leading_to")   
graph <-   create_graph(  nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges)
render_graph(graph)
}


niv <- c("A","B","C","D","E","X","Y")

temp <- data.table(EveFrom=factor(c("A","A","A","A","B","C","D","E", 
     "X", "B"), levels=niv),
EveTo=factor(c("B","C","D","E","X","X","Y","Y","Y", "C"), levels=niv))

Dia(temp,niv)
```

[image]

How can I tell diagrammer to minimize the number of edge crossings automatically?

In this simple example if C and B positions were exchanged the result wouldn't have any edge crossing.
In more complex examples we cannot remove all crossings but at least minimize it.

With visnetwork I can relocate the nodes

[image]

But it has other drawbacks, for example it doesn't let you export it as a vector graphic.

PD: This is the output with bergant solution (with labels hidden):
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the `dot` layout will produce it better. Add global attributes like this:

```
graph <- create_graph(  nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges)
graph <- set_global_graph_attrs(graph, "layout", "dot", "graph")
graph <- add_global_graph_attrs(graph, "rankdir", "LR", "graph")
```

[image: g]

Comment: Is it also possible to mimic my visnetwork result? (for example add labels on each edge or change edge width)

Comment: Labels: yes, add `label` argument in `create_edge_df` (vector of strings).

Comment: Width: use `penwidth` = 3 for example

Comment: See http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html for attributes in graphviz dot elements (graph, nodes, edges, ...)

Comment: @skan also want to point you to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422752/1305688), in addition to the link provided above.

Comment: @bergant I've added the output with your method yo my first question.  Any suggestion is welcome. As you can see visnetwork still produces a much nicer result, though sadly not vectorial. It would also be nice to have some kind of edges gaps when two edges cross each other, as with tikz.

Comment: And when I add the labels on the edges some overlap or is confusing to know what edge they pertain to.

Comment: I'm not able to find an equivalent to "font.background" to paint a white margin around the font and then avoid overlapping with the edges.

Comment: I'm using Diagrammer to create my graphs, I can export them to svg or vectorial pdf. But it has some disadvantages: It doesn't position the nodes well, and it doesn't position the labels well (quite often they olverlap with the edges or they mix with other, I need to edit and move things manually).

Comment: I've just seen there is a repulsiveforce parameter that could help creating a better representation, but it only works with the option "sfdp".  What are the options to create my example using sfdp?

Comment: What would be command line if I want a circular layout?  Or how can I fix its position to some coordinates? The only option I've seen (create_node_df with x= and y=) seems to work only when using      render_graph(graph, output = "visNetwork")  but that output can't be saved as a vectorial plot.

Answer (score 1):

use `dot` layout option (made with inspiration from [here](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html))

```
# install.packages(c("DiagrammeR"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("
digraph dot {

graph [layout = dot] # dot, neato, twopi, and circo

A -> {B C D E}
B -> {C X}
C -> {X}
D -> {Y}
E -> {Y}
X -> {Y}
}")
```

[image: dot layoutttt]

Comment: What would be command line if I want a circular layout? Or how can I fix its position to some coordinates? The only option I've seen (create_node_df with x= and y=) seems to work only when using render_graph(graph, output = "visNetwork") but that output can't be saved as a vectorial plot.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question. Make it about one thing, and use this question and answer as reference.